# Improving the performance of my "type" function

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm writing a JavaScript library, and I am using this function for type detection:

```
function type(obj){
    return  Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).replace(/([\[\]]|object|\s)/gi, "");
}
```

Their works ok, but compared to jQuery and MooTools it stinks.

http://jsperf.com/code-type-test-a-test

[image: Speed Test]

How can I improve its performance?

Comment: This is micro-optimization, don't worry about it. 7,767,355 ops/sec in FF is more than enough. How often do you check the type of something anyway?

Comment: Your test case seems completely wrong, basically you are measuring the speed of creating the function, not executing it..

Comment: @elclanrs You are right. But if I have functions in my library that are slower than functions in other libraries, then wouldn't you use the faster library?

Comment: @konijn I am pretty sure that jsperf.com puts inputs into the functions. I'll change my test just in case.

Comment: @konijn I think I have a more accurate test now.

Comment: I would not run a performance test if I don't see a difference! You need to be really more slower than other libraries IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, since there is only 1 line to review and a limited amount of ways to get the 'type` of an object

I will say that

```
function type(obj){
  return  Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).replace(/([\[\]]|object|\s)/gi, "");
}
var o = new (function Name(){})();
console.log( type(o) );
```

returns ""

whereas

```
function type(o){
  return  o !== undefined && o.constructor ? o.constructor.name : "Undefined";
}
var o = new (function Name(){})();
console.log( type(o) );
```

returns "Name" which is more correct.

It seems ( though I fudged it a little, a re-test is required ) that the second approach can be faster on IE and Safari ). All in all, I would copy the jQuery source, it takes care of all corner cases and is sufficiently fast.

Comment: Shouldn't the type of "o" be "object"?

Comment: Is this quicker that other jQuery/MooTools/My original function?

Comment: Progo, that's how it looks like for IE/Safari, it is slowest on Chrome though. @Kevindra, no, the name of the constructor is the name of the type.